# I'm programming an android app, What is causing my droid x to lock up?

Tags: android, freeze

I'm still in the process of learning how to make android apps. I'm currently trying to make my own view and use a small number of instances of it in my UI.

I have one thread in the main activity that loops and calculates an elapsed time, then it passes the elapsed time to each view to subtract that elapsed time from an set time in each view, then the view just displays the time remaining.

This all works just fine, but my phone will always lock up a bit later and I'd have to pull the battery out to reset it. I made a small game a while ago, and at one point the same thing would happen, my phone would just lock up after a moment of running the app I made. The emulator doesn't lock up, buy my phone (droid x) will.

What are some common things that result in this problem, or what specific could I be doing wrong to cause my phone to lock up?

Comment: Have you considered diagnosing the problem through logfiles? If you can understand which state the program is in when breaking, you may be able to prevent the tipping point from being reached.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything you do in an SDK application that would cause a phone to lock up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop. You should avoid unlimited loops and clear up used memory that is no longer needed.

Comment: Ok, i'll make sure that I have no loops. When clearing up memory, do I just set the variables that I do not need equal to null? thanks